# Using Lightning Record Form to Display Parent Fields

Tags: lightning-aura-components

I am trying to use lightning record form to display fields from both a child and a parent record on one screen.  I have seen this done successfully on a youtube tutorial (around 10:00)https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=OzRzu9wbUV8  When I hard code the id in, the form works, but I am having trouble getting the parent id from the child record to pass into the record form.  Are my fields referenced correctly?

```
<aura:component implements="force:appHostable,flexipage:availableForAllPageTypes,flexipage:availableForRecordHome,force:hasRecordId,forceCommunity:availableForAllPageTypes,force:lightningQuickAction" access="global" >
    <aura:attribute name="fields" type="String[]" default="['Business_Type__c','Employer_ID_Number__c','Social_Sec__c','Business_Representative_Name__c',
                                                           'Business_Representative_Title__c','Contact_Email_Address__c','Contact_Phone__c',
                                                           'VC_Called__c','VC_Resolved__c','Ready_to_Resend__c','VC_Error__c','VC_Status_Notes__c',
                                                           'VC_Resolution_Notes__c','Certified_Mail_Tracking_Number__c']" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id"/>
    <aura:attribute name="Covid_Funding" type="COVID_Funding__c"/>
    <aura:attribute name="ParentFields" type="String[]" default="['Business_Legal_Name__c','Contact_Email_Address__c']" />
    
    <!-- Display Child related fields -->
    <lightning:card class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <lightning:recordForm
                              recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                              objectApiName="COVID_Funding__c"
                              fields="{!v.fields}"
                              columns="2"
                              mode="view">
        </lightning:recordForm>
    </lightning:card>
    
    <!-- Display Parent releated fileds -->
    <force:recordData aura:id="Covid_Funding_Record"
                          recordId="{!v.recordId}"
                          TargetFields="{!v.Covid_Funding}"
                          layoutType="FULL" />    
    <lightning:card class="slds-p-around_medium">
        <!-- Using Child attribute to access parent to get final parent field & realatd ID to display parent fileds-->
        <lightning:recordForm
                              recordId="{!v.Covid_Funding.COVID_Business_Profile__c.Id}"
                              objectApiName="COVID_Business_Profile__c"
                              fields="{!v.ParentFields}"
                              columns="2"
                              mode="view">
        </lightning:recordForm>
    </lightning:card>
    
</aura:component>
```

Comment: Thank you @arut, this worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Is your component placed in a record context** (such as record page or as object specific action from record page)? Otherwise, the recordId attribute will not be populated. Details can be seen [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:hasRecordId/documentation).

**Update:**

In the component HTML's `force:recordData` replace

```
TargetFields="{!v.Covid_Funding}"
```

with

```
targetFields="{!v.Covid_Funding}"
```

The attribute is case-sensitive. Aura framework doesn't recognize the invalid attribute and won't pass the field values to `v.Covid_Funding`.

Comment: Yes; this component is placed on the COVID_funding__c page and the first lightning:recordform does work.  The second one which tries to pass the parent id in does not work.  I think the issue might be from force:recorddata, which is where I'm trying to get the parent object Id from.  I've also tried replacing recordId="{!v.Covid_Funding.COVID_Business_Profile__c.Id}" with  recordId="{!v.Covid_Funding.Id}" (as well as the object api name and the field set) and the component doesn't work, which leads me to believe it's an issue in getting the id.

Comment: You could try a few things. In the JS afterRender method, try to console.log the fields fetched by force:recordData (try a couple of fields, not just the v.Covid_Funding.COVID_Business_Profile__c.Id). This way you can confirm if all the required field values are fetched.

Comment: Second thing that you could try is to place the second recordform inside an aura IF (so it will not be rendered until certain condition evaluates to true). These may give you some more idea on what is going on.

Comment: So, the root cause is you have specified invalid attribute in force:recordData. It should be targetFields (and not TargetFields; it case-sensitive). I'll update the answer as well. You can ignore my previous comments.